# Proof of $f\chi_{\Lambda_n} \to f\chi_{\Lambda}$ in admissible spaces for compact sets $\Lambda_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, function-spaces

I have a question regarding a paper I found dealing with the problem of Phase Retrieval and I would like to know how one statement could be proven.

Here is a link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03163

At first, here is a short introduction of the setting:
We know that $(\Lambda,\mathcal{T})$ is a topology and we can write
\begin{align*}
\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Lambda_n = \Lambda
\end{align*}
where $\Lambda_n$ is a compact set with $\Lambda_n \subseteq \Lambda_{n+1}$.

Consider an admissable $\mathbb{K}$- vector space $(B_d,\| \cdot \|_{B_d}) \subseteq \text{Map}(\Lambda,\mathbb{K})$ for $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ defined by the properties, that
the set of functions with compact support $B_c^d$ is a dense subset of $(B_d,\| \cdot \|_{B_d})$ and $(B_d,\| \cdot \|_{B_d})$ is solid, i.e. for every $z \in B^d$ and $w \in \text{Map}(\Lambda,\mathbb{K})$ with $|w| \leq |z|$ pointwise, there holds $w \in B^d$ and
\begin{align*}
\|w\|=\||w|\| \leq \|z\| .
\end{align*}
In Theorem 3.13 and Theorem A.2 of the linked paper, we use that for every $f \in B^d$ there holds
 \begin{align*}
f \chi_{\Lambda_n} \overset{B^d}{\to} f\chi_{\Lambda}=f
\end{align*}
but I don't understand why this has to hold (It is stated, that this holds, because $B^d_c$ is dense in $B^d$).

If the set of compactly supported functions is dense in $(B_d,\| \cdot \|_{B_d})$, we only know that there exists a sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq B^d_c$ with $g_n \to f$, which is not necessarily $(f \chi_{\Lambda_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be proven? I am somehow completely clueless. Thanks in advance.

Edit: One idea I had was using the sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as mentioned above, to maybe use an $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ - argument, meaning that use the estimate
\begin{align*}
\|f \chi_{\Lambda_n} - f \| \leq \|f \chi_{\Lambda_n} -g_m \| + \| g_m - f \|
\end{align*}
for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and choosing $g_m$ accordingly. My problem with this approach was that the support of $g_m$ and $\Lambda_N$ sufficies no relation that I see could be utilized, so the first term on the right-hand side can't be estimated to be $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ in my opinion.

Second: I completely forgot the assumption that $(B_d,\| \cdot \|_{B_d})$ is a Banach space, sorry. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Do you know anything more about your topology $(\Lambda,\mathcal T)$?

Comment: Sadly no, because in context $\Lambda$ could be any sample / index set. The only thing that could help is that $(\Lambda,\mathcal{T})$ is $\sigma$-compact, like I have already stated. It also has the property that $\Lambda \to V^{\prime}, \lambda \to \varphi_{\lambda}$ is continous, where $V^{\prime}$ is the continous dual space of some banach space $V$, but this has no link to the asked question in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe some information about $B_d$ is missing? For example, how do we know that $f\chi_{\Lambda_n}$ is in $B_d$?

Comment: The good thing is that $f \chi_{\Lambda_n} \in B_d$ really holds true; to see this notice at first that
$|f \chi_{K_n}| \leq |f|$ holds pointwise everywhere and then use the admissability of $B_d$.
But you can be right on the missing information part. I somehow think they wanted to state that $f \chi_{\Lambda_n} \overset{B_d}{\to} f$ holds and somehow mixed up the conditions on when it does hold. They don't even use the density anywhere else, so this seems pausible. ;)

Comment: I also forgot to add the assumption that $(B_d,\| \cdot \|_{B_d})$ is a Banach space, I edited the original question, so that everyone can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the convergence does not hold as stated.
(I have not read the paper. Maybe the authors have made a mistake here, 
maybe this problem can be fixed in their theorems,
or there is additional context which makes the claim true.)

We choose $\Lambda=[0,1]$
and $\Lambda_n=\{0\}\cup [\tfrac1n,1]$.
As the space $B_d$ we choose the Banach space of bounded functions on $\Lambda$ with the $\sup$-norm.

If we now consider the constant function $f=1$ then we have
$$\| f\chi_{\Lambda_n} - f\| = \|\chi_{(0,\tfrac1n)}\| = 1$$
which is a contradiction to the claim.

Comment: You are completely right, thanks for your info! As I see it, it suffices all conditions of the paper. That's awesome.

Comment: @Mathdealer: It is true that the claim is not true as stated. What the authors had in mind, however, is probably the following: The sets $\Lambda_n$ should form an exhaustion of $\Lambda$, in the sense that $\Lambda_n$ is contained in the interior of $\Lambda_{n+1}$, each $\Lambda_n$ is compact, and $\Lambda =\bigcup_n \Lambda_n$. In this case, every compact set is contained in some $\Lambda_n$, and the claim is indeed true.

Comment: I also think that they tried to go for something like this, but it is nice to know a more formal version of what they could have wanted, thanks. :)